# SharePoint 2013 SP1 - SQL 2014 supportability

Tags: sharepoint-server

We recently migrated SP2013 with SP1 databases from SQL 2012 to SQL 2014. While I am aware that the April 2014 CU is recommended/required for a new farm installation on SQL2014, I haven't found any info regarding moving existing databases.

Everything seems to work fine while still on patchlevel SP1. Is it therefore absolutely necessary to upgrade to the latest build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per the MSFT](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/03/21/sql-server-2014-and-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx), SQL Server 2014 support added into SharePoint 2013 with April CU 2014.

But I know, we tested the SQL 2014 with SharePoint 2013 even before April CU 2014 and at that time it worked without issue.

So, we dont know what will not work without April CU unless something failed. Another thing keep in mind if you have any issue with farm and approach the MSFT, 1st thing they will tell you that apply the April CU. Just an example.

If i am you, i definitely apply the April CU 2014 or latest before moveing the Databases to SQL 2014.